# Grails Integration Test Maps

Tags: grails, integration-testing

I want to write an integration test, that tests the response of a controller, that only returns a map. Normally for unit tests, this is done as follows

```
def model = controller.showBookDetails()
assert model.author == 'Alvin Plantinga'
```

In the integration test this does not work for me. Is there another method?

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
 MyController controller = new MyController()
 def model = controller.showBookDetails()
 assert model.author == 'Alvin Plantinga'
```